# Обновляется страница с feedback - jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Плохо разбираюсь как в JS, так и в PHP. Помогите найти ошибку или подскажите как исправить.

Нужно что бы форма отправлялась, при этом страница не перезагружалась и выводилось сообщение об успешной отправки письма.

---

**Код HTML:**

```
<form id="yagaformmail2">
    <input type="text" name="yaga-name-fb" required="required" value="Ваше имя" />
    <input type="text" name="yaga-tel-fb" required="required" value="Номер телефона" />
    <input type="text" name="yaga-time-fb" required="required" value="Удобное время звонка" />

    <input type="submit" value="Перезвоните мне">
</form>
```

**Код Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yagaformmail2").submit(function() {
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "yaga-contacts-2.php",
            data: form_data,
            success: function(form_data) {
                alert("Ваша заявка на звонок успешно отправлена.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Код PHP:**

```
to = '<email>@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Обратный звонок с <site> (footer)';

$message = '
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>'.$subject.'</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Имя: '.$_POST['yaga-name-fb'].'.</p>
            <p>Номер телефона: '.$_POST['yaga-tel-fb'].'.</p>
            <p>Удобное время звонка: '.$_POST['yaga-time-fb'].'.</p>            
        </body>
    </html>';

$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$headers .= "From: <no-reply@<site>>\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

---

**С этим кодом письмо отправляется, но страница перезагружается и алерт с успешной отправкой не появляется. Как это исправить?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот в коде jQuery допишите return false;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yagaformmail2").submit(function() {
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "yaga-contacts-2.php",
            data: form_data,
            success: function(form_data) {
                alert("Ваша заявка на звонок успешно отправлена.");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```